# Filtrado en laravel con datatables no funciona con mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

Estoy utilizando Laravel 5.3 y la ultima versión del plugin dataTables.
Antes trabajaba con postgres, migre a mysql por necesidades de la db, entonces me encuentro con un problema, el filtrado personalizado me lanza un error que es el siguiente:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8_bin,NONE) and (binary,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `users` where `users`.`id` != 1 and CONCAT( users.name, ' ', users.cedula , ' ', users.nombres , ' ', users.apellidos ) like %pa%) count_row_table)

Noto que no crea los signos ('') alrededor del parámetro del `like`.

Entonces para corroborar que no sea el `collation` que coloque en la columna `name` para sensibilizar mayúsculas y minúsculas pruebo en un fidder, [aca el fiddler](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/juebnZrLpmxBEgsPweEGsD/1), pueden ver lo que les digo si simplemente colocan los ('') mysql arroja el resultado esperado, caso diferente lanza un error.

Agrego el codigo backend de mi app donde consulto la tabla:

```
public function tabla(Request $request){
    try{
        $sqls = User::select(array(
                        'users.id', 
                        'users.name', 
                        'users.cedula',
                        'users.nombres',
                        'users.apellidos',
                        'users.tipo',
                        'users.status', 
                    ))
                    ->where('users.id', '!=', Auth::user()->id);
        return Datatables::of($sqls)
        ->filter(function ($query) use ($request) {
            if ($request->has('campo')) {
                $campo = $request->get('campo');
                $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT( users.name, ' ', users.cedula , ' ', users.nombres , ' ', users.apellidos )"), 'like', "%{$campo}%");
            }
            if ($request->has('tipo')) {
                $query->where('users.tipo', '=', "{$request->get('tipo')}");
            }
            if ($request->has('estados')) {
                $query->where('users.status', '=', "{$request->get('estados')}");
            }
        })
        ->make();
    }catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
        $array = array(
            'mensaje' => $e->getMessage(),
            'codigo' => $e->getCode(),
            'sql' => $e->getSql(),
            'bindings' => $e->getBindings(),
        );
        return Response::json(array('ErrorSql' => $array));
    }
}
```

Busco el error en `mysql` y consigo [esto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_cant_aggregate_2collations), pero no logro entender porque me arroja ese error.

**Actualización 1:**
Habiendo determinado que el problema del `like` es por el `collation` de la tabla y base de datos, solo tengo un problema ¿como adaptarlo a una migración?.

Cree la migración de la siguiente manera:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AlterTablesAndDatabase extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $sql = 'ALTER DATABASE instivoc_03 CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; ';
        DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql);

        $sql = 'ALTER TABLE users CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; ';
        DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql);

        $sql = 'ALTER TABLE materiales CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; ';
        DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql);

        $sql = 'ALTER TABLE evaluaciones CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; ';
        DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql);

        $sql = 'ALTER TABLE preguntas CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; ';
        DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql);

        $sql = 'ALTER TABLE preguntas_selecciones CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; ';
        DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql);

        $sql = 'ALTER TABLE respuestas CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; ';
        DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql);
    }

    public function down()
    {

    }
}
```

¿Como determino el nombre de la `db` a la cual hace conexión? Me explico: si la conexión llegase a ser manipulada por alguien X y cambiada a otro nombre de otra `db` se tendría que editar también la migración, ¿Como podría evitar eso?.

Comment: Ya probaste estas soluciones de SO? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008287/illegal-mix-of-collations-mysql-error

Comment: Funciona la respuesta, gracias hermano, estoy adaptándolo a la migración. Hay q hacerle una modificación a la base de datos, ¿como se como se llama la base de datos desde una migración? Si se llega a editar la conexión y se cambia a otro nombre de base de datos también se tiene q cambiar la migración, ¿Como podría evitar eso?

Comment: @Shaz colocalo como respuesta para darte los pts :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomado de SO en inglés.

Ejecuta los siguientes comandos en MySQL:

```
SET collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'
```

y luego en la base de datos y/o tabla que necesites:

```
ALTER DATABASE nombre_base_datos CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci

ALTER TABLE nombre_tabla CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```